# Faster, more efficient JPEG conversion and compression on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, optimization, compression, camera, jpeg

I'm grabbing frame images from the iPhone's camera at a rate of 25fps using a resolution of 192 x 144 and a 420v, BGRA format.

I'm converting the `CVImageBufferRef`s into `UIImage`s and then calling `UIImageJPEGRepresenation(image, compressionQuality)` to get a compressed JPEG version of the image.

Using the Time Profiler in Instruments, I can see that 75% of my CPU time is spent getting the JPEG representation of the image, causing slow down with the other operations I need to accomplish in the app.

It fluctuates a little, spending less time if I set the compression to 1.0 (i.e., no compression) and spending more if I set it to 0.0 (i.e. full compression).

Is there a more efficient way to get a JPEG representation of an image from the iPhone's camera?

Can I get a JPEG representation without converting the `CVImageBufferRef` to a `UIImage` (and therefore cutting out a rather expensive Core Graphics drawing operation)?

Comment: Do you have to compress them? What are you doing with the frames afterwards?

Comment: They are being sent over a network to a peer. The network could vary, 3G, Wifi, EDGE, etc. Without compression the images (even at 192 x 144) are too large.

Comment: You might want to check some low-complexity compressors, like JPEG-LS, to see if they suit your needs. Usually JPEG-LS is lossless but there is a near-lossless option that compresses a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

Is the concern the responsiveness of the application, or the actual compression time required?  What about wrapping the JPEG code in a block and putting it on a background queue?

Comment: Good shout, but it's more about the actual time it takes to do the conversion. The work is done separately to the main thread already (as much as possible, anyway) but I can't send the JPEG data out over the socket until its done converting...

Comment: Actually - that may not be true?  It might be over-architecting the problem, but you could start the encoding in a background thread, keeping a shared memory space for the output buffer, and then start sending as you encode.  In most non-Wifi cases, I reckon it's going to take longer to send than to encode.  If your buffer runs out of data - that should be fine, most HTTP connections (I assume you are POST-ing the data) don't time out for at least 30 seconds.  Obviously the main problem with this approach is the need to get into the nitty-gritty of CFNetwork to chunk the data for sending.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't over HTTP. It's a direct UDP connection between the peers. TCP showed a performance hit due to the overhead. Streaming the JPEGs as they're being encoded may be something to look into, but this is to simulate 'video' (or maybe MotionJPEG) in lieu of more appropriate video streaming APIs that aren't available on the iPhone. I fear that streaming the JPEG won't be sufficient as a `frame` will still only be able to be displayed after it's fully sent.